# Definite integral $\int_{1}^3{\frac{dx}{x^2-6x+8}} $

Tags: definite-integrals

How to continue?

$$\int_{1}^3{\frac{dx}{x^2-6x+8}} =$$
$$ =\left[  \frac12 \ln\left|\frac{x-4}{x-2}\right| \right]_{1}^3 =$$
$$= \frac12 \ln\left|\frac{-1}{1} \right| - \frac12 \ln\left|\frac{-3}{-1} \right|$$

How to solve integrals like this, when it is not define?

Comment: You cannot perform the integration, because the integral does not converge in that range.

Comment: How should I test it if it converge in that range?

Comment: Solving $x^2 - 6x + 8$ gives you two solutions: 

$$x_{1; 2} = \frac{6\pm \sqrt{36 - 32}}{2} = \frac{6\pm 2}{2}$$

So $x_1 = 4$ and $x_2 = 2$

the second value, $x=2$ belongs to the extrema of integration, so there is a pole along the integration path, which makes the integral to diverge.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln(1)$ *is* defined. It is $0$. You may be thinking of $\ln(0)$, which is not defined.

Comment: yes of course, sorry, there is another reason why it is not possible calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the function cannot be integrated because it is too large near $x=2$.  Plot the function, and you will see.

Comment: Yes I saw it, but how is it possible know it without plot the function using wolframalpha?

Comment: Factor the polynomial in the denominator.  It is $(x-2)(x-4)$, so the denominator goes to zero at $x=2$.

Comment: Thanks, it means that it cannot be integrated for numbers witch give me 0 in the denominator in original function?

Answer (score 1):

About your last question: "it means that it cannot be integrated for numbers witch give me 0 in the denominator in original function?", the answer is: Depends. The reason because this particular function is not integrable in [1,3] is because it's not bounded,which you can see with Wolfram if you wish, but there's another way of knowing it: Since the denominator is a polynomial, it is continuous. Besides, it becomes $0$ when $x=2$. This means $\lim_{ x  \rightarrow 2} x^2-6x+8=0$. So the denominator approaches zero as much as you wish by making x near 2, and so $r(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2-6x+8}$ goes to infinity, meaning r(x) is not bounded near 2. However if we consider the function: $f:[1,3]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ if $x\not =2$ and $f(2)=0$, then it is true that the denominator gives $0$ in $x=2$, but it's clearly integrable on $[1,3]$.